# Invalid syntax in if-else statement

Tags: python, syntax

I have written the following code and it returns a syntax error in the "else". **else:^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax**. I am new to python but I do not know if I am missing something.

```
def pressure_pa(self, altitude_m):
        atm_layer = self.atm_layer_id(altitude_m)
        atm_coef = 34.1632
        if atm_layer > 1:
            layer_alt_m = altitude_m-self.alt_layer[atm_layer-1]
        if atm_layer == 1:
            p0 = 101325.0
            T0 = 288.15
            k0 = -6.5
            pres_pa = p0*pow(T0/(T0+k0*altitude_m/1000), atm_coef/k0)
        elif atm_layer == 2:
            p0 = 22632.06
            T0 = 216.65
            pres_pa = p0*math.exp(-atm_coef*(layer_alt_m/1000)/T0)
        elif atm_layer == 3:
            p0 = 5474.889
            T0 = 216.65
            k0 = 1.0
            pres_pa = p0*pow(T0/(T0+k0*layer_alt_m/1000), atm_coef/k0)
        elif atm_layer == 4:
            p0 = 868.0187
            T0 = 228.65
            k0 = 2.8
            pres_pa = p0*pow(T0/(T0+k0*layer_alt_m/1000), atm_coef/k0)
        elif atm_layer == 5:
            p0 = 110.9063
            T0 = 270.65
            pres_pa = p0*math.exp(-atm_coef*(layer_alt_m/1000)/T0)
        elif atm_layer == 6:
            p0 = 66.93887
            T0 = 270.65
            k0 = -2.8
            pres_pa = p0*pow(T0/(T0+k0*layer_alt_m/1000), atm_coef/k0)
        elif atm_layer == 7:
            p0 = 3.956420
            T0 = 214.65
            k0 = -2.0
            pres_pa = p0*pow(T0/(T0+k0*layer_alt_m/1000), atm_coef/k0)
        elif atm_layer == 8:
            pres_pa = math.exp(2.159582E-06*((altitude_m/1000)**3)-4.836957E-04*((altitude_m/1000)**2-0.1425192*altitude_m/1000+13.47530)
        else:
            pres_pa = math.exp(3.304895E-05*((altitude_m/1000)**3)–0.009062730*((altitude_m/1000)**2)+0.6516698*altitude_m/1000-11.03037)
        pres_pa=pres_pa*(273.15+self.dtemp_K)/273.15
        return pres_pa
```

Comment: check your parenthesis at the line before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you surround your exponents with parentheses. Check the last exponential of the last elif (atm_layer == 8). You need a parentheses after the 2.

```
        pres_pa = math.exp(2.159582E-06*((altitude_m/1000)**3)-4.836957E-04*((altitude_m/1000)**2**)**-0.1425192*altitude_m/1000+13.47530)
```